# If $X_t$ is an AR(2) process, what is $Y_t := X_t - X_{t-1}$?

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive, moving-average, differencing

Q: If $X_t$ is an AR(2) process, what is $Y_t := X_t - X_{t-1}$?

Attempted solution:

$X_t = \phi_1 X_{t-1} + \phi_2 X_{t-2} + W_t$, where $W_t$ is white noise.

\begin{equation} \begin{split} Y_t &:= X_t - X_{t-1} = \phi_1 X_{t-1} + \phi_2 X_{t-2} + W_t - \phi_1 X_{t-2} - \phi_2 X_{t-3} - W_{t-1} \\
\end{split} \end{equation}

But what can we say about $Y_t$?

Comment: this sounds like a self study question. if you agree, consider adding self-study tag :-)

Comment: Reorder your terms such that you have a linear combination of $X_{t-i}$ terms and a linear combination of $W_{t-j}$ terms. Then have a look at ARMA models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we write it with characteristic polynomials the relations will look like below $$Y_t=(1-B)X_t, \ \ \ \ \ \ \  X_t(1-\phi_1B-\phi_2B^2)=W_t$$

Then, the relation between $Y_t$ and $W_t$ can be written with
$$Y_t=\frac{1-B}{1-\phi_1B-\phi_2B^2}W_t \rightarrow Y_t(1-\phi_1B-\phi_2B^2)=(1-B)W_t$$

Converting it back yields the following ARMA(2,1) model.
$$Y_t-\phi_1 Y_{t-1}-\phi_2 Y_{t-2}=W_t-W_{t-1}$$